# To create a frequency table with dplyr to count the factor levels and missing values and report it

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Some questions are similar to this topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377819/countif-equivalent-in-dplyr-summarise) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469975/creating-a-frequency-table-in-r), as an example) and I know one solution that works, but I want a more elegant response.

I work in epidemiology and I have variables 1 and 0 (or NA). Example: 
Does patient has cancer?
**NA or 0 is no**

**1 is yes**

Let's say I have several variables in my dataset and I want to count only variables with "1". Its a classical frequency table, but dplyr are turning things more complicated than I could imagine at the first glance.

My code is working:

```
dataset %>%
  select(VISimpair, HEARimpai, IntDis, PhyDis, EmBehDis, LearnDis, 
         ComDis, ASD, HealthImpair, DevDelays) %>%  # replace to your needs
  summarise_all(funs(sum(1-is.na(.))))
```

And you can reproduce this code here:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c(NA,1),100), var2=rep(c(NA,1),100))

dataset %>% select(var1, var2) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(1-is.na(.))))
```

But I really want to select all variables I want, count how many 0 (or NA) I have and how many 1 I have and report it and have this output
[image: desired output]

Thanks.

Comment: If you provide a minimal, reproducible example, it would help. Look into `dplyr::count`

Comment: Hello, @CPak. You can reproduce this question with the code I provide: library(tidyverse)
dataset <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c(NA,1),100), var2=rep(c(NA,1),100))

dataset %>% select(var1, var2) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(1-is.na(.))))

Comment: Sorry, you're right - could you specify what kind of output you're looking for?

Comment: Sure, @CPak I want this output
Varname_1 varname_2 varname_i
1      955        19        19     32     27  

but I don`t want to achieve this output by this dirty method sum(1-is.na(.)), but for something like sum(filter(all vars == 1))

Comment: @CPak, I have edited my question.

Comment: I am not sure that you `sum(1-is.na(.))` does what you want. It subtracts only if there is a missing, but not if there is a zero in the data, and hence counts 1s and 0s.

Comment: Hello, @CPak, you are right. This code only works because my variables have only NA and 1. I think I`ll have to follow @bala83 code using gather.

Answer (score 2):

What about the following frequency table per variable?

First, I edit your sample data to also include 0's and load the necessary libraries.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dataset <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c(NA,1,0),100), var2=rep(c(NA,1,0),100))
```

Second, I convert the data using `gather` to make it easier to `group_by` later for the frequency table created by `count`, as mentioned by CPak.

```
dataset %>%
    select(var1, var2) %>%
    gather(var, val) %>%
    mutate(val = factor(val)) %>%
    group_by(var, val) %>%
    count()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   var, val [6]
  var   val       n
  <chr> <fct> <int>
1 var1  0       100
2 var1  1       100
3 var1  NA      100
4 var2  0       100
5 var2  1       100
6 var2  NA      100
```

Comment: Yes! It works pretty well. As long dplyr is so smooth, I thought it was possible to report this output without having to use gather. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty method to do this is to coerce your input into factors:

`dataset$var1 = as.factor(dataset$var1)
dataset$var2 = as.factor(dataset$var2)
summary(dataset$var1)
summary(dataset$var2)`

Summary tells you number of occurrences of each levels of factor.